# Magento version error!

Tags: magento-1.7

I have installed an extension.
But in the magento connect manager, there is some error.

> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Skrill_Hosted_Payment_Solution 1.0.7:
>   requires PHP version >= 5.4.0 and <= 5.6.13 current is: 5.2.17

In the past question and answers, it can be added

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

But still there is an error. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Well.

The module clearly states it needs php 5.4 as min and 5.6 as max versions.

You seem to be usung 5.2.

About time you update php?
Consider the fact that php 5.4 is already EOL, you would want to update to min 5.5

Best way to check your php version is via a call to phpinfo.